# Twilio Validate Requests from Subaccounts

Tags: twilio

I want to be able to validate the requests to my server from Twilio are from twilio [as shown here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests). When using my primary account, this works just fine (I use a node wrapper but I manually have followed the steps and can match their `x-twilio-signature`.

When I use subaccounts, though, it fails every time. I attempt to use the subaccount's auth token as well as the parent's as the key to the SHA, but nothing works, nor do the node wrappers. There is no documentation about subaccounts and validation. Anyone used subaccounts and also tried validating incoming requests?

Answer (score 0):

From a support interaction it looks like the OP spent some time debugging [Twilio-Node](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install) and found:

> The Node module encodes the URL, so it creates something like
>
> `https://987f3bb1.ngrok.io/api/twilioWebhook%3Ffoo=1`
>
> whereas you guys are not encoding the query string delimiter, so your
>   URL looks like
>
> `https://987f3bb1.ngrok.io/api/twilioWebhook?foo=1`
>
> I am now recreating the URL myself and passing it in as part of the
>   options, and this does not get formatted so it is working now. I've
>   [created an issue in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/145) for this as well with suggestions
>   to fix.

Comment: I know it's old, maybe you can still help...
Did you end up sending the sub-account token as authToken to the validateExpressRequest function or the "parent" token?
I have no query string, validating the request with the sub-account token works for me but I need to use the "parent" token and that just doesn't seem to work.